# Use '.' as a decimal separator in PhpExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm using PhpExcel to generate xlsx files,
When I tried to fill cells with numbers using formats depending on the user language, I encountered some problems;

For French format ,I used:

```
$activeSheet->getStyle($chosenCell)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode("# ##0");
1234 ----->1 234 (**correct**)
```

For English format ,I used:

```
$activeSheet->getStyle($chosenCell)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode("#,##0");
1234 ----->1,234 (**correct**)
```

But for Spanish format ,I used:

```
$activeSheet->getStyle($chosenCell)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode("#.##0");
1234 ----->1234. (**Not Correct**)
```

How can I use '.' as a decimal Separator ?

Comment: Always use EN_US format (`"#,##0"`) and let the copy of MS Excel that you open the file in handle displaying it according to locale settings itself... the MS Excel GUI does this for you based on its setting, as long as you use standard EN_US settings when creating the file

Comment: Thanks for your response, the problem is that I have to control the number formats using some variables and not let MSExcel handle numbers automatically .

Comment: Then you're pretty scuppered.... PHPExcel is intended to generate files for viewing in MS Excel (and other spreadsheet programs) using the standards of their file formats. Internally, these formats don't use individual locale formats, but one standard format, and then allow the viewing program (the MS Excel GUI) to localise that at the point of display.... if you want to write different locale formats for every value, then you'll have to treat everything as a string, and have to write multiple files with each set of strings formatted differently for every locale you want to send it to.